# Linear regulators in series

Tags: linear-regulator

I'm helping a friend review a schematic. It's a battery-powered project with three rails: battery (AAA 3 x 1. 5 V) and two linear regulated rails (LP5907MFX-1.8 and LP5907MFX-3.3). The 3.3V reg is powered directly from the battery, the 1.8V reg is powered from the 3.3V output. The design is done by a serious player, but I don't understand why they don't parallel them (both powered by battery)? Then the current capability of 3.3V isn't limited by the 1.8V draw.

Could it be that 1.8V draws much more power, so in this series setup, some heat is dissipated in the 3.3V regulator before the rest is dissipated in the 1.8V regulator?

Any other pros/cons with series regulators?

Comment: Please draw the exact circuit or post the schematic you have. Also include links to data sheets.

Answer (score 4):

Watts is watts.  The total power dissipated in the regulators is the same in both series and parallel configurations.

You are correct that the dissipated power is distributed differently in each case.  That could be the reason, but without knowing the output currents there are no numbers to compare.

Another possible reason is physical layout, either on a PC board on on an off-board heatsink.

Another possible reason is control.  Having the regulators in series guarantees their power-on sequence.

Another possible reason is control.  If the first regulator in the series has an enable input, this is effectively an enable input for all downstream regulators, even if they do not individually have enable inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Total power lost is almost the same either way (assuming Iq of the 1.8V regulator does not change much with input voltage). Current limits (and current limits due to thermal considerations) will be different, in general, since the 3.3V regulator has to carry all the current.

Depending on the regulators in a mixed voltage system there may be subtle issues with power supply sequencing wherein having a 1.8V rail that is (even briefly) higher than the 3.3V rail could cause issues. Deriving the 1.8 from the 3.3 is generally safer, but may not be sufficient.

Sometimes it even makes sense to use two similar regulators with the same input voltage source (to spread heat, or to provide a quieter rail for analog circuits).

Answer (score 0):

The losses due to power dissipation in linear regulators are proportional to Vin - Vout. Lower voltage drop equals to lower losses.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The OP is asking why both 3.3V and 1.8V regulators aren't connected directly to the battery. The actual setup has [battery] --> [3.3V reg] --> [1.8V reg]. The total power dissipated in both cases will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons I can think where this kind of regulator topology may be beneficial.

1. If the input source is AC, or DC with ripple (such as the output of a SMPS), you may need multiple regulator stages to give you the ripple rejection you need at the load.  Since the input power is DC, this probably isn't the reason.
2. The application may need isolation between some of the loads.  This is where a picture from the poster would help.
3. You need to spread the power dissipation around to multiple parts, because of thermal considerations.
4. Another guess (because that's all I can do given the info in the question) is that the raw battery voltage (4.5 V) may not be available where the 1.8 V regulator is.

Comment: "need to spread the power dissipation around to multiple parts"  I've played these games when available parts are restricted to what is on hand.  Maybe there's a desire to keep the variety of inventoried parts low.  There's nothing _wrong_ with placing the regs in series, as you can potentially (hehe) spread the heat around the PCB in an attempt to keep the reg temps lower.  There is no efficiency gained, but PCB real estate is [can be] lost to the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Another advantage of the series configuration: When powering up both rails sequentially via the enable input of the 1.8V controller, you can reduce the amplitude of the inrush current. First the capacitors of the 3.3V circuit are charged and then the capacitors of the 1.8V circuit.

In a parallel configuration, all capacitors would be charged simultaneously causing a higher inrush current.